# Regexp to literally interpret \t as \t and not tab

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to match a sequence of text with backslashed in it, like a windows path.

Now, when I match with regexp in python, it gets the match, but the module interprets all backslashes followed by a valid escape char (i.e. `t`) as an escape sequence, which is not what I want.

How do I get it not to do that?

Thanks
/m

EDIT:
well, i missed that the regexp that matches the text that contains the backslash is a (.*). I've tried the raw notation (examplefied in the awnsers), but it does not help in my situation. Or im doing it wrong.
EDIT2: Did it wrong. Thanks guys/girls!

Comment: Can you give an example of the behaviour?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use double backslashes with r like this

```
>>> re.match(r"\\t", r"\t")
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0xb7ce5d78>
```

From python [docs](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#raw-string-notation):

> When one wants to match a literal
>   backslash, it must be escaped in the
>   regular expression. With raw string
>   notation, this means r"\". Without
>   raw string notation, one must use
>   "\\", making the following lines of
>   code functionally identical:

```
>>> re.match(r"\\", r"\\")
<_sre.SRE_Match object at ...>
>>> re.match("\\\\", r"\\")
<_sre.SRE_Match object at ...>
```

Comment: it's a single double-backslash :)

Comment: well, i missed that the regexp that matches the text that contains the backslash is a (.*). I've tried the raw notation above, but it does not help in my situation. Or im doing it wrong.

Comment: Can you update your question with an example and your actual regexp?

Answer (score 1):

Always use the `r` prefix when defining your regex. This will tell Python to treat the string as raw, so it doesn't do any of the standard processing.

```
 regex = r'\t'
```

Comment: -1 This is actually incorrect. If `r'\t'` were used as a string, it would be a backslash followed by a 't'. However, if this is used as a regular expression, it will match a tab character, which is what the OP is trying to avoid. As Nadia's answer said, if you want to make a regex to match a backslash followed by a 't', you need to escape the backslash, e.g. `re.compile(r'\\t')`.

Comment: @Variadicism I just did that. Not getting a tab match.

Comment: @Steve, I just tried and did.
`string = "\t\toption\t";
import re;
print(re.match(r'\t', string)) => <_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7f19b2dfd5e0>;
print(re.match(r'\\t', string)) => None`

Comment: @Variadicism What version of python are you using?

Comment: @Steve, that was on Python 2.7.12. I tried it on Python 3.5.2 and got the exact same results except that the match from the first `re.match` printed slightly differently: `<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 1), match='\t'>`. These results are expected; the Python version should not matter unless a certain version has a bug.